# Spacing consecutive characters in string with Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to translate a string and put an underscore before any uppercase character. The closest I have got is:

```
out=in.replaceAll("([^_])([A-Z])","$1_$2");
```

but with `"ABCDEF"` it returns `"A_BC_DE_F"`, I guess because after considering "AB", it doesn't look at "BC" because "B" was already in the previous match. Of course I could apply it twice, but is there a more elegant solution?

There is also:

```
out=in.replaceAll("([A-Z])","_$1");
```

but it adds a leading `"_"`.

Java 1.8, if that matters

Comment: Try `replaceAll("(?<!_)([A-Z])","_$1");`

Comment: To avoid a leading `_` go with `replaceAll("(?<!_|^)([A-Z])","_$1");` or `replaceAll("(?<!_)(?<=.)([A-Z])","_$1");`

Comment: You may use `.replaceAll("(?<=[^_])[A-Z]","_$0");`, just put the negated character class into a positive lookbehind. There is no need to enclose the whole consuming pattern with capturing parentheses, `$0` backreferences stands for the whole match value. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/uANATA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may put the `[^_]` negated character class into a *non-consuming* positive lookbehind

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=[^_])[A-Z]","_$0");
```

Note that there is no need to enclose the whole consuming pattern with capturing parentheses, `$0` backreference stands for the whole match value.

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/uANATA):

```
System.out.println(
      "ABCDEF".replaceAll("(?<=[^_])[A-Z]","_$0")
);  // => A_B_C_D_E_F
```

Answer (score 4):

Why using regex??

```
String underscoreUppercase(String target){
    StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
    boolean first=true;
    for(char c:target.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c) && !first){//to ommit leading underscore
             b.append('_');
         }
         first=false; 
        b.append(c);
    }

   return b.toString();   
}
```

for `ABCDE` it will yeld `A_B_C_D_E`

Comment: Unexpected? What is the expectaton then? *I'm trying to translate a string and put an underscore before any uppercase character*

Answer (score 3):

You can use positive lookahead here

Regex : `([A-Z])(?=([A-Z]))` where `(?=([A-Z]))` is a non-consuming positive lookahead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String in = "ABCDEF";
    String out = in.replaceAll("([A-Z])(?=([A-Z]))", "$1_");
    System.out.println(out);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternativly you may split the string at each uppercase char and join back using underscore

```
String in  = "ABCDEF";
String out = String.join("_", in.split("(?=\\p{Upper})"));
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: Yes, good solution too. I had envisioned something like this but couldn't make it work.